# How do I randomly distribute a set of numbers across a single column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a set of continuous "1" values across column A Eg: `11111`. I'd like to distribute this randomly across column B with spaces in between Eg: `1   1 1  1`. Not really sure how to go about this. I'd like to do this for 600 values in column B. Any help is appreciated!

[image: Vertically distributed values example]

Comment: "Across column A" can you clarify what you mean by that? Same with "Randomly across column B". Generally I don't think of the word "Across" when I think of a column so this is very confusing. Perhaps a screenshot of what you intend to do would be illuminating?

Comment: Ah, I didn't mean across like a row. I meant vertically.

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula could work:

```
=IF(ROUND(RAND(),0)=1,1,"")
```

It will generate a random number between `0` and `1`, round it to the nearest integer (so `0` or `#`), return `1` if the result is `1` and nothing if it is `0`

Populate as many cells as you need in the column you want

Edit:

To limit the number of `1`s appearing use the following formula in cell `B2` and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(ROUND(RAND(),0)=1,COUNTIF(B$1:B1,1)<6),1,"")
```

Where `6` is the maximum number of ones that will appear, you can change it to any integer or reference a cell that has the maximum number of `1`s you want to appear

Comment: I'd like to populate 600 values in column B, this might take a while to do

Comment: What about it would take a long time? Just drag the formula down - unless there's something missing from your question..

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1373214/how-to-fill-a-large-series-over-10-000-rows-in-microsoft-excel-without-draggin/1373218#1373218) may be useful

Comment: I understand now! Thank you!

Comment: Is there anyway I can limit the frequency of 1s appearing?